# Spark Livy Server: How does Python script return a json object?

Tags: json, rest, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera

We are using Spark for ML and data processing and the request comes in from a web based UI front end. So we are using the Livy REST server for this. The code runs to completion correctly based on the tutorial here:
http://gethue.com/how-to-use-the-livy-spark-rest-job-server-api-for-submitting-batch-jar-python-and-streaming-spark-jobs/

However, I don't know how to return the intended output. Currently the python code 'main' ends as

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

  sc = SparkContext('local')
  #do some spark processing to create 'result' dictionary
  print json.dumps(result, indent=4)
```

This sends the result to 
`curl localhost:8998/batches/0/log`
along with all the verbose of spark-submit. How can I instead return the json object so the web UI (Node.js based) can query for it, such as 
`localhost:8998/batches/0/output`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output into hdfs and you can use that file location url to get the output into node. It is better to redirect the output of python to a location in hdfs using some unique id and save that unique id in the database so that when getting the output you can refer to that id for getting output file.